# R Shiny - how to label horizontal and vertical lines on reactive ggplot? (Date & Numerical columns)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

does anyone know how i can label the horizontal and/or vertical line on reactive ggplot in shiny?

All my data is based on filtered datatable, therefore the intercept changes depending on the input data. Filtered data is showed on the ggplot, furtehrmore the user can choose x and y axis to display. One of choices on x axis is date column: which makes it difficult (plus some of the columns are numbers/some factors).

My horizontal and vertical lines are reactive as well (depending on filtered data)

Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

data_melt <- structure(list(Block = 1:20, Limits = structure(c(18L, 
                                                               18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
                                                               18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L), .Label = c("0.13", "0.15", "0.18", 
                                                                                                         "0.2", "0.21", "0.23", "0.25", "0.26", "0.28", "0.3", "0.32", 
                                                                                                         "0.37", "0.4", "0.45", "0.48", "0.5", "0.52", "0.55", "0.56", 
                                                                                                         "0.59", "0.6", "0.64", "0.7", "0.8", "1"), class = "factor"), 
                            Date = structure(c(16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 
                                               16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 
                                               16439, 16439, 16439, 16439, 16439), class = "Date"), X = c(0.24, 
                                                                                                          0.25, 0.23, 0.24, 0.23, 0.24, 0.22, 0.24, 0.21, 0.22, 0.23, 0.24, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 5.5, NA_real_, 
                                                                                                          NA_real_, NA_real_, 0.27)), .Names = c("Block", "Limits", "Date", 
                                                                                                                                                "X"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(selectInput(inputId = "yaxis", 
                               label = "Y-axis (Plots/Histogramm)",
                               choices = list("X" = "X"), 
                               selected = c("X")),
                   selectInput(inputId = "xaxis", 
                               label = "X-axis (Plots)",
                               choices = names(data_melt), 
                               selected = "WertNr")),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      tabBox(status = "primary", width = NULL, height = "1000px", 
             tabPanel(title="Tabelle filtern", div(style = 'overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll;max-height: 950px; position:relative;', 
                                                   dataTableOutput("tabelle"))),
             tabPanel("plot", plotOutput("plot", height=800)))))
      )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tabelle <- renderDataTable({

    datatable(data_melt,class = 'cell-border stripe', filter="top", 
              options = list(pageLength = 50, columnDefs = list(list(width = '200px', targets = "_all"), list(bSortable = FALSE, targets = "_all"))))
})

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    filtered_data <- input$tabelle_rows_all
    data_filt <- data_melt[filtered_data,]  

    vec <- quantile(data_filt[ ,input$yaxis], c(.00135,.50,.99865), na.rm = TRUE)

    data_filt$Limits <- as.numeric(as.character(data_filt$Limits))

    widedata <- subset(data_filt, select=c(input$xaxis, input$yaxis))

    longdata <- melt(widedata, id.vars=c(input$xaxis), variable.name="Variables", value.name="Value_y")

    longdata$WertNr <- as.numeric(1:nrow(longdata))


        ggplot()+ 
          geom_line(data=longdata, aes_string( x=input$xaxis, y="Value_y"),colour= "gray40", size=1.5) + 
          geom_hline(data=data_filt, aes(yintercept=(Limits*2)*0.75), linetype = "dotdash", size = 1, color="red") +
          geom_hline(data=data_filt, aes(yintercept=0), linetype = "dotdash", size = 1, color="red") +
          scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(n = 10)) +
          theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=15), 
                axis.text.x=element_text(size=15), 
                axis.title.x = element_text(size=18, face="bold"),
                axis.title.y = element_text(size=18, face="bold"),
                legend.position="bottom", legend.title=element_blank(),
                legend.text=element_text(size=14))
      })
}

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thanks for any help!

I have tried `geom_text` , `annotate`, and even created separate `data.frame`, however it just gives me an error, when the date on x axis is choosen.

```
toly <- ((data_filt$Limits*2)*0.75)
txty <- data.frame(x=1.5, y=toly[1], lab="OSG") in `renderPlot` and then

geom_text(data=txty, aes(label=lab), size=5, angle = 90, hjust = 0, vjust = 0) in ggplot --> is not working (i get error straight away)

 Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y
```

after adding x & y

```
 geom_text(data=txty, aes(x=1.5, y=toly[1],label=lab), size=5, angle = 90, hjust = 0, vjust = 0)
```

It is working (However the label moves on the scale to match x=1.5, and i really would like it to stay on x axis in one place no matter of the x scaling) for numerical columns but for date column:

```
Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only
```

i am trying to find solution that will let me label the horizontal line no matter what type of column has been choosen for x axis (numeric, date or factor) and let the label stay at the same position (next to the horizontal line) no matter what numbers are on scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution to my problem.

I had to define which columns are date, numerical and factor and then i used the If...else statements in `server`, and created for each of them separate plot.

```
 if (input$xaxis == "1st factor column" | input$xaxis == "2nd factor column"){
  g <-ggplot(...) + geom_line() + 
    annotate("text", x=0.5, y=...)
  }
else{
  g <-ggplot(...) + geom_line() + 
    annotate("text", x=min(data_filt[ ,input$xaxis]), y= ...)
  }g
```

Not elegant solution but its working :)

Answer (score 1):

If the x-values of your plot have the type `Date`, the x-values of your `geom_text` object must also be an object of the type `Date`. Try

```
geom_text(data=txty, aes(x=as.Date("2015-01-04"), y=toly[1], label=lab),
          size=5, angle = 90, hjust = 0, vjust = 0)
```

and it works.

But anyway I did not really get what you intend to do. Please try to give a minimal example focusing on your problem the next time.

Comment: Hello Patrick, I just want to label the horizontal line, and the problem is that it is  reactive ggplot.The user can choose **x** and **y** axis. From my sample data, You can see that the columns for **x** axis  can be: numerical & date columns. Therefore I cannot define simply **the position of the horizontal line label on x axis**. So i am trying to find solution that will let me label the horizontal line no matter what type of column has been choosen for x axis and let the label stay at the same position no matter what numbers are on scale (like in the upper right corner or so)

Comment: OK, but a float value for a `Date` dimension does not make sense for ggplot. Perhaps you could use something like `mean(your_x_data)` to get the middle x position independently of the data type of `your_x_data`.

Comment: I have tried Your tipp for mean(x_data): `geom_text(data=data_filt, aes(x=mean(input$xaxis), y=toly[1],label="OSG"), size=5, hjust = 0, vjust = 0)`. However i got an error: `Warning in mean.default(input$xaxis) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA`

Comment: ` selectInput(inputId = "xaxis", 
                               label = "X-axis (Plots)",
                               choices = names(data_melt)` -> it contains all columns, which means: Block (numeric), Limits(factor),date (date), X (numeric)...